# What is the value of this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the relation $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z=0$ , I am having some hard time to understand why the different values of $F_z$, is it $-1$ from the middle part or $0$ from the right? if both are correct depending on the context, what would be them?

Comment: $F_z = - 1$. It cannot be zero unless for all values of (x, y, z) when plugged in, results $F  = 0$, only then $F_z = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of $ F _ z $ will depend on context.

If $ F ( x , y , z ) = f ( x , y ) - z $ is the definition of $ F $ as a function of $ 3 $ variables, and the fact that $ F ( x , y , z ) = 0 $ is secondary, then $ F _ z $ is $ - 1 $.  A more unambiguous way to state this would be $ \mathrm D _ 3 F ( x , y , z ) $, where $ \mathrm D _ i $ means the derivative of a function with respect to the $ i $th variable; if $ F $ is the function from $ ( x , y , z ) $ to $ f ( x , y ) - z $, then it's undeniable that $ \mathrm D _ 3 F ( x , y , z ) = - 1 $.

On the other hand, perhaps $ F $ and $ f $ are two independently defined functions, and the point of the equation is to restrict attention to a particular curve, where the two surfaces $ F ( x , y , z ) = 0 $ and $ f ( x , y ) = z $ intersect.  On that curve, $ F _ z $ is $ 0 $.  Indeed, we could parametrize the curve by $ z $ and take the derivative of anything along it, and the derivative of $ f $ (which equals $ z $ on the curve) would be $ 1 $, while the derivative of $ F $ (which is constant on the curve) would be $ 0 $.  A more unambiguous way to write this is $ \mathrm d F ( x , y , z ) / \mathrm d z $, making it clear that we're thinking of $ F ( x , y , z ) $ as depending on $ z $ alone.  Then since $ F ( x , y , z ) = 0 $, of course $ \mathrm d F ( x , y , z ) / \mathrm d z = 0 $.

An intermediate case is where $ F ( x , y , z ) = f ( x , y ) - z $ is the definition of $ F $, but we still only want to look at the place (now forming a surface rather than a curve) where this is $ 0 $.  Then the derivative of $ F $ along this surface is still $ 0 $.  We could parametrize this surface by $ x $ and $ y $, or by $ x $ and $ z $, or by $ y $ and $ z $; in either of the latter two cases, we could speak of $ F _ z $ as the partial derivative with respect to $ z $.  In the two cases, $ F _ z $ would have slightly different meanings, but the value would be $ 0 $ either way.  A more unambiguous way to write this would be $ \partial F ( x , y , z ) / \partial z | _ x $ or $ \partial F ( x , y , z ) / \partial z | _ y $; the subscript indicates which variable is held fixed in the partial derivative.  (Such subscripts are usually left out, but only because the context makes them clear, and here the context is ambiguous.)  On the surface $ z = f ( x , y ) $, $ F $ is constant, and so both $ \partial F ( x , y , z ) / \partial z | _ x = 0 $ and $ \partial F ( x , y , z ) / \partial z | _ y = 0 $.

If you can give some details of the context in which you found this, then we could probably pin it down better.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x,y)-z=0$, $f(x,y)=z$.  Therefore, $F(x,y,z)=z-z=0$.

The reason that $F_z$is not $-1$ is that $f$ is actually equal to $z$.  That is, even though it doesn’t appear as so, $f$ is a function of $z$.  So when taking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$, the derivative is not $0$.  In fact, it’s $1$!